# Groovy If-else and short-hand notation behaves differently

Tags: groovy

I am facing a problem that I am unable to figure out.

I have a floating-point number. I want to return an integer if the decimal part is 0, otherwise the original floating point number should be returned. 
The following if-else works correctly and returns 20.

```
def sampleNumber = 20.0
if(sampleNumber == Math.round(sampleNumber)) return sampleNumber as int
else return sampleNumber as float
```

However, this does not work. This returns 20.0

```
def sampleNumber = 20.0
return sampleNumber == Math.round(sampleNumber)? sampleNumber as int : 
sampleNumber as float
```

Can anyone please suggest what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `as float` is applied to the whole expression. But it doesn't make much sense: if I put both expressions in brackets, e.g.

```
return (sampleNumber == Math.round(sampleNumber)) ? 
    (sampleNumber as int) : 
    (sampleNumber as float)
```

it still does not work as you could expect. The only working solutions I've found is to use `.toInteger()` and `.toFloat()` methods instead:

```
return (sampleNumber == Math.round(sampleNumber)) ? 
    sampleNumber.toInteger() : 
    sampleNumber.toFloat()
```

If you remove `as float` from the first example and return e.g. String like `'float'` then `sampleNumber as int` returns what you expect. I'm gonna investigate it to find the exact reason of this weird behavior.